# CMake - Set up a configurable project without repeating building everything each time cmake is run

Tags: c++, cmake

I am migrating a large legacy codebase from autotools to CMake, and we have some behaviour that we'd like to preserve. However, my naive initial reimplementation of the build system in CMake has resulted in the entire project being rebuilt every time cmake is invoked. I believe this is happening because of the way that `include_directories` is being used, along with a lack of cache variables, but I'd like to double-check here if a better solution exists than the one I'm thinking of.

The original reimplementation was done in CMake 2.8 (corporate slowness, hooray), but I've managed to get hold of 3.14, so I've tried to tidy it up a little. I'd like to use some more modern features if possible.

---

### Legacy Autotools setup

`conf.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR_=`dirname $0`
${DIR_}/configure \
  --some-flag=yes \
  --some-other-flag=ok \
  --some-dependency=/home/deps/dependencyOne \
  --some-other-dependency=/home/deps/dependencyTwo \
"$@"

exit %?
```

configure.in contains the decoding logic to set these dependencies up:

```
AC_ARG_ENABLE(some-dependency),
[
if test "x$some_dependency" != "xno" ; then
  if test -d "${enableval}"; then
    DEPONE_DIR=$enableval
  else
    AC_MSG_ERROR("Must specify dependencyOne directory!")
  fi
  DEPONE_INCLUDES="-I$DEPONE_DIR/include"
  DEPONE_LDFLAGS="-L$DEPONE_DIR/lib -ldepone"

  #etcetera
fi
]
```

Running `./conf.sh` from the desired `build` directory generates the Makefiles and such. After this, we run `make`. If we change a source file, it only rebuilds that source and its dependees (dependors? Is there a word for this). If we change a Makefile.am, again, it's smart enough to not rebuild everything.

---

### Current CMakeLists.txt setup:

We want to be able to switch dependencies on and off in the build, and the way we do this is through this configure script. I originally recreated the existing setup closely in CMake as shown below:

Config script:

```
#!/bin/bash
libs=(
  -Dsome-dependency=/home/deps/dependencyOne
  -Dsome-other-dependency=/home/deps/dependencyTwo
)

args=(
  ${libs[@]}
  -Dsome-flag=yes
  -Dsome-other-flag=ok
)

cmake "${args[@]}"
```

Root CMakeLists.txt:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.12)
PROJECT(myProject)

#some language-specific setup (standard etc)

if(some-dependency)
  link_directories(${some-dependency}/lib)
  include_directories(${some-dependency}/include)
endif()

if(some-other-dependency)
  link_directories(${some-other-dependency}/lib)
  include_directories(${some-other-dependency}/include)
endif()
```

I noticed that if I switch off a line in the config script, running cmake will have cached the value and still act as if it was enabled, which I don't want. So I committed this cardinal sin:

End of root CMakeLists.txt:

```
unset(some-dependency CACHE)
unset(some-other-dependency CACHE)
```

Now, every time I run the configure script (and by extension `cmake`), it rebuilds *everything* when I run `make`. My guess is that this happens because of `include_directories` being reset every time, resulting in everything being marked as dirty.

My supposed solution to this is twofold:

- Use `target_include_directories`
- Check if the value supplied from the config script via -D matches an existing CACHE entry, and if so, do nothing. I don't think this will work, given -D sets a variable in cache.

Is there a better way of getting this done? I get the impression that my attempt at it is fairly naive and simplistic, and if a better solution exists, I'd really love to know about it.

Comment: "I noticed that if I switch off a line in the config script, running cmake will have cached the value and still act as if it was enabled, which I don't want." - Yes, if you pass parameter `-DFOO=1` when run `cmake` the first time, and the second time you don't specify `FOO`, then CMake treats it as being set. In other words, the second and other `cmake` invocations specify what should be **modified** since the previous run, not what should be **set**. If you no longer want CMake to treat `FOO` as being set, then pass `-UFOO` parameter.

Comment: Yes, that is how the cache works. I'd like to have explicit behaviour without the developer having to remember what is in-cache or not each time, and merely switching options between `-D` and `-U` isn't going to fix the problem of cmake marking everything as dirty every time and rebuilding everything.

Comment: Actually, CMake is too smart enough to not rebuild everthing on `make` if something changed in `CMakeLists.txt`. So your problem could be not in CACHE variable, but *somewhere else*. The code you currently include into the question post doesn't create any library or executable. So we can only guess what is going wrong. Please, prepare [mcve], describe how do you call `cmake` the first and the second time, and specify a file which is rebuilt unexpectedly.